# Segbot Documenation

Tags: navigation, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Any documentation/instructions available for using Segbot package for navigation?
I am trying to implement autonomous navigation on a Segway based Robot. Currently, the only available sensor for navigation is hokuyo.  So far I have been able control the Segway using libsegwayrmp and use hector_slam with the hokuyo node. I am now trying to use the segbot  code for navigation . I have couple of questions regarding the same:

1. Can we use the map generated by hector slam or is gmapping preferred?
2. What is the purpose of  segbot_gui ( question_dialog_plugin) with regard to navigation?
3. Also to run the navigation stack for segbot : roslaunch  segbot_navigation  navigation.launch?
   Is there anything I am missing?
   Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/170246/segbot-documenation/) by [pnambiar](https://answers.ros.org/users/15286/pnambiar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2014-05-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apologies for the lack of documentation. I need to work on that pretty soon to hand over the project to someone else, but I'm not sure if updated documentation will be sufficient for people outside our lab. I will update my answer when I've added this documentation.

1. It does not matter how the map was generated.
2. segbot_gui is not used in navigation. None of the launch files in segbot_navigation use it.
3. You've got the right command. You'll also need to supply a map file, as the default one won't work for you.

Good Luck!

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2014-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0